# Need help exploiting preg_replace() vulnerability

Tags: php

I'm doing a CTF security challenge, I found a "downloader.php" page with a possible vulnerability.

it lets me download any file from the server, including "downloader.php" itself, the problem is running through all known php files, I couldn't find an access point.

I'm thinking of entering through the downloader.php itself, but it has a filename treatment with preg_replace, and I need to work around that.

Here is the code of the file "download.php":

```
<?php

$dnpath = $_GET['name'];
$dnpath = str_replace("..",".", $dnpath);
$dnpath = str_replace("..",".", $dnpath);
$dnpath = str_replace("..",".", $dnpath);
$dnpath = str_replace("..",".", $dnpath);
$dnpath = str_replace("..",".", $dnpath);
$dnpath = str_replace("..",".", $dnpath);
$dnpath = str_replace("..",".", $dnpath);
$dnpath = str_replace("..",".", $dnpath);
$dnpath = str_replace("..",".", $dnpath);
$dnpath = str_replace("..",".", $dnpath);
$dnpath = preg_replace("/[ #\&\+\%@=\\\:;,'\"\^`~|\!\?\*$#<>()\[\]\{\}]/i", "", $dnpath);


$lastDate = '0';

$file = "C:/test_root/".$dnpath; 
if (!file_exists($file))
{
    echo "File not exist : ";
    echo $file;
    exit;
}

Header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); 
Header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
Header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$dnpath\""); 
Header("Pragma: no-cache"); 

ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
return true;
?>
```

i tried something like:

`downloader.php?name=alert(%22XSS%22)`

but without success because of preg_replace

Comment: You forgot to name the target of that "challenge".

Comment: the target is a local server from my college, created for this challenge

Comment: Not sure what you expected `?name=alert(%22XSS%22)` to achieve here (since that's client side script outside any JS context). In my opinion, questions like these shouldn't be answered here, since we can't confirm that we wouldn't unknowingly be helping in exploiting a real live server.

Comment: That was not what I asked ...